# what should I do to be able to create large PDF files without error?

Tags: php, pdf

I'm creating a pdf file on fly using fpdf of PHP from the database but when there are a lot of data in my db , either the file cant be created completely and just half of it comes out, or nothing will happen or I get run-time error what should I do to be able to create large PDF files without error?

large pdf :

The code is like :

```
require('lib\fpdf.php');
require ('lib\pdf.php');
include ('lib\bukaDb.php');

$pdf = new PDF('P','pt','A4');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->setY($pdf->tMargin);

for ($i=0; $i<count($var); $i++){   
//Do something , show data
//$pdf->Ln(20);
}

// Finally, produce the PDF!!

$pdf->Output();
```

And my table has hundreds of rows, I cant use set time limit function, any other recommendation?

Comment: How do you create your PDF? Please show some code. How much data is "a lot of data"? How large is a "large PDF"?

Comment: I edit my question please advice me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create PDF files (using fpdf) with hundreds of pages without any problem, so I guess it's your code that is collecting / displaying data that causes the request to time out.

When your HTTP request takes long to complete (more than 10 seconds) then it's probably your script simply taking too much time to complete.

I really think the problem is what happens inside that `for` loop. Try to create a *simple* dummy PDF with about the same amount of pages. If that works, you know that you have to search the problem inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Dear Udo G, I'm creating more than 20 different documents with different contents, while my db is not that full, they work fine but when they are large...

Tnx bro. however, I cant send Email to my clients but you think saving file to the server and showing the link after creation is better than making the file on-fly?
link|edit|flag
 
answered 5 hours ago
A Farhang Dareshuri
1

Comment: You should optimize your script and/or database so that it can generate the document within a few seconds. If that is not possible you may need to think about generating the document in the background (asynchronously) and send it to the user later (there are various solutions for that). However, I would always try to do anything to speed up the script itself, so that the PDF is generated quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is probably timing out. Try disabling the built-in time limit:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

If you host your site or app on a shared-hosting server though, make sure you are allowed to do this. Some web hosters (including mine) frown upon using lots of server resources for tasks like this.

Answer (score 1):

Move you script to crontab and set saved pdf as file. Once your script finished, set it to send email telling you that the process finished.

As rough pseudo-code:

```
require('lib\fpdf.php');
require ('lib\pdf.php');
include ('lib\bukaDb.php');

$pdf = new PDF('P','pt','A4');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->setY($pdf->tMargin);

for ($i=0; $i<count($var); $i++){   
//Do something , show data
//$pdf->Ln(20);
}

// Finally, produce the PDF!!
$savefile = "/path/to/output/dir/output.pdf";
$pdf->Output($savefile,'I');

mail('admin@example.com', 'PDF Generator', "PDF has been generated at $savefile");
```

Then, all you have to do is, save it to somewhere on your server and set it's path as crontab:

```
/path/to/php/cli/php /path/to/your/saved/php/pdf_generator.php
```

Please note that you have to:

- make sure your `$savefile` directory is writable by script.
- use php cli, not by accessing script via browser as it will also affected by time limit.

Comment: Tnx bro. however, I cant send Email to my clients but you think saving file to the server and showing the link after creation is better than making the file on-fly?

Comment: yeah, for large files, it's better to create that manually. Not on the file. If you can't send email to client, you can set it to send email to yourself. It's just a way to automatically let you know files has been created.